# Unable to "npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native" either expo cli or react-native cli

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

Im trying to install tensorflow for react native but when when i try to install it throw all these errors in the picture link attached below.
Does anyone know what it means and what should i do? i have tried either a expo cli project and a react-native cli project but the result is the same error!
[see console.log error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1PRT.png)

Comment: From the image you have shared, I can tell that you have a missing peer dependency in there. Install react@17.0.2 and this particular issue should disappear but be aware you might still need to solve more dependency issues.